# Checking for an updated SQLite database

Tags: objective-c, ios, database, sqlite

How do I handle updating my SQLite database file when I update my application. Basically when I update, the database needs to be updated to. I thought about adding a table to the database that would have the database version, but my only concern with that is how would I read from two databases with the same name. One would be the one in the Documents Directory (the old one) and the new one (with the same name) would be in the Main Bundle. The application it self does not require any user preferences to be stored in the database so I dont have to worry about over writing users data. But the application does make updates to the database from the internet, but these will ultimately be incorporated into the next release. Any have any tips on how to handle this?

Comment: Why not just update everything from the internet and forget about updating when you update the app?

Answer (score -1):

You could use 'NSFileManager' to copy the database from the application bundle into the Documents directory before you open it.